# sharepoint 2010 announcements prompt for user credentials

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

My sharepoint publish page has announcements list and it has anonymous access. when i open it in firefox it shows the title and summary. when i click on the title to see the body message, it prompts user credentials.

Is there a way not to prompt credentials and show the full message?

How to hide the username and posted date in the announcements?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the body contain any images or other assets that are in a folder that is not accessible to anonymous users? This may also include the Style Library, if there is no published version of some items.

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find out what URL exactly causes the `403 Forbidden` authentication prompt.

Comment: Hi Michael,Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

the form has announcement and contacts webpart,  when i click on any link in announcement webpart (or) contacts, prompts for user credentials.
In fiddler i see "/sites/bfs/prototype/Lists/ACS%20Contacts" requesting webpart.
Please advise me.